# 14.04 - Nividia GPU driver install fails

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have tried installing any version of the Nvidia gpu drivers in an attempt to move away from 331 which has been causing and issue upgrading the kernel and hasn't been fixed.
I have tried using the additional drivers method, and via the terminal.
I haven't been able to find anyone who has had this issue.

This is what I get from the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fonts-dejavu-extra libgconf2-4 liblog4j1.2-java ttf-dejavu-extra tzdata-java
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libcuda1-352 nvidia-opencl-icd-352
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libcuda1-346 nvidia-346
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libcuda1-352 nvidia-352 nvidia-opencl-icd-352
0 to upgrade, 3 to newly install, 2 to remove and 65 not to upgrade.
Need to get 7,923 kB/75.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 49.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu/ trusty/main libcuda1-352 amd64 352.30-0ubuntu0~xedgers14.04.1 [7,923 kB]
Fetched 7,923 kB in 1min 20s (98.8 kB/s)                                       
(Reading database ... 761062 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libcuda1-346 (346.87-0ubuntu0~xedgers14.04.1) ...
Removing nvidia-346 (346.87-0ubuntu0~xedgers14.04.1) ...
Stopping nvidia-persistenced
nvidia-persistenced: no process found
Done.
Removing all DKMS Modules
Done.
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-346-prime/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-346-prime/alt_ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode
INFO:Disable nvidia-346
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/libbrscandec2.so.1 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/libbrcolm2.so.1 is not a symbolic link

Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4.2) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-59-generic
Selecting previously unselected package libcuda1-352.
(Reading database ... 760756 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libcuda1-352_352.30-0ubuntu0~xedgers14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcuda1-352 (352.30-0ubuntu0~xedgers14.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-352.
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-352_352.30-0ubuntu0~xedgers14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-352 (352.30-0ubuntu0~xedgers14.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-opencl-icd-352_352.30-0ubuntu0~xedgers14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-opencl-icd-352 (352.30-0ubuntu0~xedgers14.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-opencl-icd-352_352.30-0ubuntu0~xedgers14.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/OpenCL/vendors/nvidia.icd', which is also in package nvidia-opencl-icd-331 331.113-0ubuntu0.0.4
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-opencl-icd-352_352.30-0ubuntu0~xedgers14.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove old drivers first. Run

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

and try again.

Comment: That worked, but why wasn't  the additional drivers system doing it?

Comment: Because you install drivers from ppa. It is not supported.